Fatal error: During inheritance of IteratorAggregate: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function default_error_handler(), 4 passed in
error in my moodle platform:

Fatal error: During inheritance of IteratorAggregate: Uncaught
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
default_error_handler(), 4 passed in
/home/u369948337/domains/napronailsacademy.com.ar/public_html/moodle/lib/navigationlib.php
on line 897 and exactly 5 expected in
/home/u369948337/domains/napronailsacademy.com.ar/public_html/moodle/lib/setuplib.php:421
Stack trace: #0
/home/u369948337/domains/napronailsacademy.com.ar/public_html/moodle/lib/navigationlib.php(897):
default_error_handler() #1
/home/u369948337/domains/napronailsacademy.com.ar/public_html/moodle/lib/setup.php(599):
require_once('/home/u36994833...') #2
/home/u369948337/domains/napronailsacademy.com.ar/public_html/moodle/config.php(27):
require_once('/home/u36994833...') #3
/home/u369948337/domains/napronailsacademy.com.ar/public_html/moodle/index.php(30):
require_once('/home/u36994833...') #4 {main} in
/home/u369948337/domains/napronailsacademy.com.ar/public_html/moodle/lib/navigationlib.php
on line 897

this is line 897
class navigation_node_collection implements IteratorAggregate, Countable {


This is probably because you are trying to run Moodle in PHP 8
Encountered the same issue when I was migrating the servers, and when I switched the PHP version to PHP 7, it worked flawlessly.
